# Temp table is present in the tempdb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a stored procedure inside which I am creating a temp table with some fieds(just for entity framework to identify the return fields else it returns only int) and When I am running my stored procedure #EmpTab is create and says that table is already exist no matter even if I delete this manually. Once I run sp then it says the same.

```
alter proc test
as
begin

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmpTab ') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #EmpTab 
END


create table #EmpTab (
ID int,
Name varchar(20),

);

select empId, EmpName into #EmpTab from employee;

select * from #EmpTab ;
drop table #EmpTab ;

end
```

Comment: use 'Insert into'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    IF you check your script you will find #EmpTab Is Getting Created Twice 
    1)1st time you create Temp Table.
    2)While Inserting Data INTO Temp Table.
    Both time you Create Same Temp_Table.

        CREATE proc test
        AS
        BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT empId, EmpName INTO #EmpTab 
        FROM employee;

        SELECT * FROM #EmpTab ;
        DROP TABLE #EmpTab ;

        SET NOCOUNT OFF       
        END
```

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**, your solution runs sp sucessfully but when executing sp says invalid #EmpTab

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**, your solution works great. thanks.

Comment: @Saleem welcome Bro you can Upvote me if solution work for you

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**, just one more question here, after selecting records from temp table why entity framework does not recognise the return columns even I explicitly creating the temp table as above. Is there any better solution to that.

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**,NOP, entity framework still returns int value after setting SET NOCOUNT ON AND THEN OFF

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**, I did SET FMTONLY ON altered proc without running it, included in proj, then again SET FMTONLY OFF and then ran the proc and when I check entity framework identifies the return columns. And can you check my below post/comment and advise me on that.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT ... INTO` creates the temp table. So does `CREATE TABLE`.

Either get rid of the explicit `CREATE TABLE` or replace the `SELECT ... INTO` with an `INSERT` if you want to retain the explicit create.

BTW there is no need for a temp table here anyway. The whole procedure code could be replaced with

```
select empId, EmpName from employee;
```

Is this just a test procedure with dummy code?

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert into ,since already table has been created

```
Insert into #Emptab(ID,Name)
select empId, EmpName from employee;
```

Comment: **Alfaiz Ahmed**, Just for my information, want to know that this stored procedure is used in my application and the application is used by many users. Is it good to have local temp table instead global temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of below code :

```
    alter proc test
    as
    begin

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmpTab ') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #EmpTab 
    END


    create table #EmpTab (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(20),

    );

    Insert into #Emptab(ID,Name)
    select empId, EmpName from employee;

    select * from #EmpTab ;
    drop table #EmpTab ;

    end
```